# Handling large XML files with relational data - Java

Tags: java, xml, linux, awk, sed

There are tons of questions around this topic, but none of them seem to have a clear-cut answer to this specific problem.

I get a large dump of XML files from a data provider and put together these files add up to about a few GBs (ranging between 6-20 GB). There is a master XML file with a bunch of references to other files, which in turn can reference other files as well.

**Example:**

master.xml

```
...
<region>123</region>
...
```

region.xml

```
...
<region>
  <id>123</region>
  <zone>345<zone>
  ...
</region>
...
```

zone.xml

```
...
<zone>
  <id>345</id>
  <name>Zone 1</name>
  <top_trade>ABC123</top_trade>
    ...
</zone>
...
```

trade.xml

```
...
<trade>
  <id>12334</id>
  <alias>ABC123</alias>
  <name>Insurance</name>
  ...
</trade>
...
```

Final output:

```
<region>
   <id>123</id>
   <zone>Zone 1</zone>
   <top_trade>Insurance</top_trade>
</region>
```

Now to answer the obvious question - why not use an RDBMS to query and spit out the required data? There are a few reasons:

- The DB will not be used beyond the initial transformation and I'd like to avoid introducing transient components in the architecture
- The input is text and the output is text (I'll be exporting this to a JSON file which will be used to seed a few systems) and going through the protocol change, adding a DB engine on top and running queries seems like an overkill on an efficient file system like Linux (I'm not considering running this application on Windows)
- Though the example provided looks perfectly relational, the data is not as clean. For instance there may be multi-valued tags for a field, each of which references one of the other files - introducing a many-many mapping and that means introducing additional tables (on top of the already bloated set) to support the data structure

The most recommended solution in Java (for similar problems) is using a HashMap and constructing each row in incremental loops, but it seems to be pretty inefficient IMHO (there are about 8-10 large files) and given the size of the files, the HashMap could get fairly large.

Questions:

- Is there any other way to handle this problem efficiently in Java?
- If not, is it better to handle this using Linux features like sed or awk? * If sed or awk (or a similar Linux feature) is my best bet, given that this execution needs to be event-driven (REST or AMQP), is it a good practice to use runtime exec in my Java code?

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: I would give the recommended solution a try. It's hard to beat hash tables. Note (if I understand, correctly) that you only have to load the reference files (region, zone, trade, ...) into the hash tables. Then you can read the master file in a stream fashion, writing your final output as you go.

Comment: Using XQuery might help solving your problem, although I'm not sure about efficiency. It is well integrated in Java, supports reading multiple XML files and streaming them.